# Multi-GPU CIFAR10 example in tensorflow: aggregated loss

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, multi-gpu

In the tensorflow [multi-gpu CIFAR 10 example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py), for each GPU they compute the loss (*lines 174-180*)

```
for i in xrange(FLAGS.num_gpus):
  with tf.device('/gpu:%d' % i):
    with tf.name_scope('%s_%d' % (cifar10.TOWER_NAME, i)) as scope:
      loss = tower_loss(scope)
```

When a few lines below (*line 246*), they evaluate `loss` with

```
_, loss_value = sess.run([train_op, loss])
```

what loss is exactly computed?

I looked at the `tower_loss` function, but I don't see any incremental aggregation over all GPUs (towers).

I understand that the whole graph is being executed (over all GPUs), but what value of the loss will be returned? Only the `loss` on the last GPU? I don't see any aggregation on the actual `loss` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The computed `loss` is indeed only the loss on the last GPU. In the code they use a Python variable `loss` to access the Tensor.

You can also validate this easily by printing the Python variable representing this tensor. E.g. adding `print(loss)`on *line 244* (with a 2-GPU setup), will return:

```
Tensor("tower_1/total_loss_1:0", shape=(), dtype=float32, device=/device:GPU:1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the gradient computed from the loss of each GPU tower is appended by the tower_grads list, and average_grad function averages all gradients. I don't quite understand the question here, because tower_loss() function is within one GPU, the aggregation and sync of all GPU outputs are collected out of it. The previous answer of print will definitely print out the last GPU result, because it is last output of the for loop of all GPU runs, but it does not mean that only the last loss is collected.